# Vue JS with Offline State

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to disable enable element when user is offline/online but `offline.js` is not working and navigator.Online is not work when user doesn't refresh the page. so i tried with below code:-

In x.js

```
window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
  isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
    if (!online) {
      this.online = false
    }
  })
})

window.addEventListener('online', () => {
  isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
    if (online) {
      this.online = true
    }
  })
})

isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
  if (!online) {
    this.online = false
  }
})
```

I want to export it using `export { isOnline }` but it is saying

> Can't resolve symbol

Comment: make sure `isOnline` is defined first. Also, you probably want to export it like this: `export default { isOnline }`